# Set javascript property using string selector

Tags: javascript, object

I want to set object properties using a string selector. I have a string `model.name` and I have a object to store the values in. Instead of storing the value in `object[model.name]` I want to store it in `object[model][name]`.

How can that be accomblished with javascript/jQuery or a javascript/jQuery plugin?

Comment: Why downvote? Ok, is a simple question. But anyone here was a noob in the past. Or not?

Comment: I tried the most of the common ways of setting data, that i know from php, i usually don't work with javascript, i normally work with back-end programming creating ORM systems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function setObjectPathValue(source, path, value) {
    var parts = path.split('.'), len = parts.length, target = source;

    for (var i = 0, part; i < len - 1; i++) {
        part = parts[i];
        target = target[part] == undefined ? (target[part] = {}) : target[part];
    }
    target[parts[len - 1]] = value;
    return target;
}

var obj = {};
setObjectPathValue(obj, "level1.level2.level3.name", "test");
alert(obj.level1.level2.level3.name);
```